# Problem with relative path when applying js file from another directory

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

I'm trying to load JS file in another directory to an HTML file that I'm working on. I tried the code below but it seems to be not working with error 404. What is the problem here?

```html
<script th:src="@{../../one-ui/src/assets/_js/pages/dashboard.min.js}"></script>
```

**Path of the js file:** `JavaProject\src\main\resources\one-ui\src\assets\ _js\pages\dashboard.min.js`

**Path of the html file:**  `JavaProject\src\main\resources\templates\dashboard\graph.html`

Comment: What other framework are you using? It would help to edit your question and add the tag.

Comment: I'm currently working on spring boot framework. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Phix just sent a [suggested edit request](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31024735) on the post.